How to plot half arrow head in PyPlot
I am planning to draw vector diagrams in Julia using PyPlot.
In order to draw an arrow with a regular full shape I am using the following Julia code:
using PyPlot
figure()
plot([0,0.8],[0,0.4],"k")
annotate("", xy=(0.8, 0.4),
    xytext=(0, 0),xycoords="data",
    arrowprops=Dict("edgecolor"=>"k", "facecolor"=>"k",
        "width"=>1, "linestyle"=>"-",
        "headlength"=>10,
        "headwidth"=>5),
    annotation_clip=false)
axis("square")

This is, what the Julia code shows:

However, sometimes I need arrows with only half the head displayed. Manually draw, such arrows look like:

How is it done, that only half of the vector head is drawn (either upper or lower side)?
The arrow demo site https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/fancyarrow_demo.html does not give any hints ...

see this demo https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/arrow_demo.html

the key part of that demo being shape="right" or shape="left", although that is an option for arrow not annotate

@tmdavison Thanks for your comment. I guess I have to consider to switch from annotate to arrow:
using PyPlot
close("all")
figure()
plot([0.2,0.8],[0.2,0.4],"k")
annotate("", xy=(0.8, 0.6),
    xytext=(0.2, 0.4),xycoords="data",
    arrowprops=Dict("edgecolor"=>"k", "facecolor"=>"k",
        "width"=>1, "linestyle"=>"-",
        "headlength"=>10,
        "headwidth"=>5),
    annotation_clip=false)
arrow(0.2,0.6,0.6,0.2,width=0.01,head_length=0.1,head_width=0.08,shape="left",
    length_includes_head=true, facecolor="black",color="black")
arrow(0.2,0.8,0.6,0.2,width=0.01,head_length=0.1,head_width=0.08,shape="right",
    length_includes_head=true, facecolor="black",color="black")
axis("square")

This leads to:

